# Pandas: undo accumulation (e.g. cumulative sum)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, cumulative-sum

I have received data with accumulated numbers. Is there a smart way to deaccumulate data, so I have it month by month and not stacked on top of each other?

(Check the example xlsx here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yELrJdZmi3CFJccYSi5U6GGDW-Awp5spHDnsDyshBe0/edit?usp=sharing.)

Example input:

```
Date    SalesRep    itemA   itemB
01-01-2018  Jakob   5       10
01-01-2018  Adomas  10      20
01-01-2018  Thomas  15      30
01-02-2018  Jakob   50      30
01-02-2018  Adomas  100     40
01-02-2018  Thomas  150     65
```

Desired output:

```
Date    SalesRep    itemA   itemB
01-01-2018  Jakob   5       10
01-01-2018  Adomas  10      20
01-01-2018  Thomas  15      30
01-02-2018  Jakob   45      20
01-02-2018  Adomas  90      20
01-02-2018  Thomas  135     35
```

Best Regards,

Przemyslaw

**P.S. UPDATE**

What about the case if the data is not incrementing every month?

Example input:

```
Date    SalesRep    itemA   itemB
01-01-2018  Jakob   5       10
01-01-2018  Adomas  10      20
01-01-2018  Thomas  15      30
**01-02-2018    Jakob   50      30**
01-02-2018  Adomas  100     40
01-02-2018  Thomas  150     65
**01-03-2018    Jakob   50      30**
01-03-2018  Adomas  102     60
01-03-2018  Thomas  155     75
```

What about the case of Jakob who is not incrementing every month then your solutions are not working? Can I somehow specify the parameters to check that and subtract only if there is a change?

Comment: Add your example to the text of your question rather than a link to an external document.

Comment: Your update doesn't make much sense. The solutions work fine when there is no change -- by definition the output for the month in this case should be 0. Add example output.

Answer (score 4):

You can groupby the sales rep and take the row-wise difference.  Then merge the datasets back together.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['01-01-2018', '01-01-2018', '01-01-2018', '01-02-2018', '01-02-2018', '01-02-2018'],
    'SalesRep': ['Jakob', 'Adomas', 'Thomas', 'Jakob', 'Adomas', 'Thomas',],
    'itemA': [5, 10, 15, 50, 100, 150],
    'itemB': [10, 20, 30, 30, 40, 65]})

df_diff = df.groupby('SalesRep').diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
df.loc[:, ['itemA', 'itemB']] = df_diff.where(df_diff, df.loc[:, ['itemA', 'itemB']])

df
# returns:
         Date SalesRep  itemA  itemB
0  01-01-2018    Jakob      5     10
1  01-01-2018   Adomas     10     20
2  01-01-2018   Thomas     15     30
3  01-02-2018    Jakob     45     20
4  01-02-2018   Adomas     90     20
5  01-02-2018   Thomas    135     35
```

Comment: Hi great example how can i import the data from excel then in pandas to got the same results?

Comment: What about the case if the data is not incrementing every month?

Comment: You will have to provide more data for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Basically using `DataFrame.groupby` and `diff`. Unfortunately the first rows, lacking a previous row for the difference, are `nan`, and this required some messy cleaning up. There may be a prettier way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['01-01-2018', 'Jakob', 5, 10],
        ['01-01-2018', 'Adomas', 10, 20],
        ['01-01-2018', 'Thomas', 15, 30],
        ['01-02-2018', 'Jakob', 50, 30],
        ['01-02-2018', 'Adomas', 100, 40],
        ['01-02-2018', 'Thomas', 150, 65],
        ['01-03-2018', 'Jakob', 60, 30],
        ['01-03-2018', 'Adomas', 120, 45],
        ['01-03-2018', 'Thomas', 200, 75]
    ],
    columns=['Date', 'Sales rep', 'item A', 'item B']
)

cum_columns = ['item A', 'item B']

result = df.merge(
    df.groupby('Sales rep')[cum_columns].diff(),
    left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['', '_uncum']
).fillna({'{}_uncum'.format(cum_column): df[cum_column] for cum_column in cum_columns})

print(result)
Out:
         Date Sales rep  item A  item B  item A_uncum  item B_uncum
0  01-01-2018     Jakob       5      10           5.0          10.0
1  01-01-2018    Adomas      10      20          10.0          20.0
2  01-01-2018    Thomas      15      30          15.0          30.0
3  01-02-2018     Jakob      50      30          45.0          20.0
4  01-02-2018    Adomas     100      40          90.0          20.0
5  01-02-2018    Thomas     150      65         135.0          35.0
6  01-03-2018     Jakob      60      30          10.0           0.0
7  01-03-2018    Adomas     120      45          20.0           5.0
8  01-03-2018    Thomas     200      75          50.0          10.0
```

Comment: Hi great example how can i import the data from excel then in pandas to got the same results?

Comment: You should Google that, there is plenty of information on the internet. But `pd.read_excel` is the relevant function.

Comment: What about the case if the data is not incrementing every month?

Comment: Your question is about incrementing data, so what do you mean the case where the data isn't incrementing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach using `shift`. It essentially subtracts the previous number. It assumes the DataFrame is already in the correct order (just use `DataFrame.sort_values` first if it isn't). I think this is nicer as it gives an in-place one-liner.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['01-01-2018', 'Jakob', 5, 10],
        ['01-01-2018', 'Adomas', 10, 20],
        ['01-01-2018', 'Thomas', 15, 30],
        ['01-02-2018', 'Jakob', 50, 30],
        ['01-02-2018', 'Adomas', 100, 40],
        ['01-02-2018', 'Thomas', 150, 65],
        ['01-03-2018', 'Jakob', 60, 30],
        ['01-03-2018', 'Adomas', 120, 45],
        ['01-03-2018', 'Thomas', 200, 75]
    ],
    columns=['Date', 'Sales rep', 'item A', 'item B']
)

group_by_columns = ['Sales rep']
cum_columns = ['item A', 'item B']

df[cum_columns] -= df.groupby(group_by_columns)[cum_columns].shift(1).fillna(0)

print(df)
Out:
         Date Sales rep  item A  item B
0  01-01-2018     Jakob     5.0    10.0
1  01-01-2018    Adomas    10.0    20.0
2  01-01-2018    Thomas    15.0    30.0
3  01-02-2018     Jakob    45.0    20.0
4  01-02-2018    Adomas    90.0    20.0
5  01-02-2018    Thomas   135.0    35.0
6  01-03-2018     Jakob    10.0     0.0
7  01-03-2018    Adomas    20.0     5.0
8  01-03-2018    Thomas    50.0    10.0
```

Comment: There was a typo where the expanded example I provided didn't increment the month, but it didn't really break the answer. I've edited to fix the typo... does this resolve your confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less general but prettier version of Denziloe's answer:

```
def reverse_cumsum(series):
    series_zeroed = pd.concat([pd.Series([0]), series])
    return series_zeroed.diff()[1:]
```

This can be used on your example by ordering by date, then applying this after grouping by the desired column ('SalesRep' in your case).